permitAll expression for Spring Security 6
I'm trying to rewrite these Spring Security 5 rules:
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
  }

Into Spring Security 6:
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.securityMatchers(matchers -> matchers
            .requestMatchers(RegexRequestMatcher.regexMatcher("/"))).csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable);
    return http.build();
  }

I can't find where I have to add .permitAll(). Do you know how I can implement this?

You need to use authorizeHttpRequests
http.authorizeHttpRequests(registry -> registry.requestMatchers("/", "/login", "/api/v1/actuator/**",                          ).permitAll()


Since this seems to be a followup question to Cannot resolve method 'regexMatcher' in 'HttpSecurity' and you're kind of struggling with upgrading to Spring Security 6 here some information:

http.securityMatchers vs http.authorizeHttpRequests:

The securityMatchers configuration is used to predetermine whether to enter the specific SecurityFilterChain at all or not. If it matches, and only if, then all the other settings for this specific filter will be considered, whether they may be further route restricitions, header configurations or CSRF.
The authorizeHttpRequests will handle specific routes and allow or restrict calls. It is chained after the securityMatchers. If no securityMatchers is provided then this SecurityFilterChain will handle all endpoint calls. In such a case this SecurityFilterChain should be ordered as the last one.

The MvcRequestMatcher is the standard matcher used by Spring MVC. It is Spring's own creation and best fit whenever possible. The AntMatcher is a relic from Apache Ant Project and should only be used when required, for eg the H2 database still relies on this matcher. The RegexRequestMatcher is a regex matcher as the name implies and is bit more resource costly, but gives you a broad scope to specify routes, although it should also only be used when required.

Now, to wrap up your question and give a real world example with three SecurityFilterChain methods in place, one for resources, one for the H2 database used during development and one which handles all the other endpoints, here a code snippet which should clear some things a bit up:
/**
 * {@link SecurityFilterChain} for H2 database requests only.
 *
 * <p>Spring MVC requestMatchers() uses by default {@link MvcRequestMatcher}. Since the H2 console
 * is not controlled by Spring MVC, we must force Spring Security 6 to use AntPathRequestMatcher.
 *
 * @return a configured {@link SecurityFilterChain} for H2 database requests
 */
@Bean
@Order(10)
@Profile("development")
public SecurityFilterChain h2FilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                         @Value("${spring.h2.console.path:/h2-console}") String h2ConsolePath) throws Exception {

    return http
        .securityMatchers(matchers -> matchers
            /* https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12546#issuecomment-1382891839 */
            .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(h2ConsolePath + "/**")))

            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll())

            /* The H2 console runs in a frameset. Thus, we need to set 'X-Frame-Options' from 'deny' to 'sameOrigin'. */
            .headers(header -> header.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin))

            /* Otherwise login into H2 won't work. */
            .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)

        .build();
}

/**
 * {@link SecurityFilterChain} for resources only.
 *
 * @return a configured {@link SecurityFilterChain} for resource requests
 *
 * @see <a href="https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10938#issuecomment-1062359527">
 *     Don't use WebSecurityCustomizer for web.ignoring()</a>
 */
@Bean
@Order(20)
public SecurityFilterChain resourceFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    return http
        .securityMatchers(matchers -> matchers
            .requestMatchers("/favicon.ico",
                             "/css/**",
                             "/fonts/**",
                             "/img/**",
                             "/js/**",
                             "/webjars/**"))

        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll())

        .requestCache(RequestCacheConfigurer::disable)
        .securityContext(SecurityContextConfigurer::disable)
        .sessionManagement(SessionManagementConfigurer::disable)

        .build();
}

@Bean
@Order(30)
public SecurityFilterChain mvcFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    return http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(true)
            .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/", "/error/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/secrets/**").authenticated()
            /* more requestMatchers here to come */
            .anyRequest().denyAll())

        .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
        
        .build();
}

